# Inner npm install 'axios' modules fails in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vuejs2, webstorm

I get an error when I install the `axios` module in WebStorm, and I don't know how to solve it.

[image]

[image]

This is my package.json.her, but I not changed:

```json
{
  "name": "todolist",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  }
}
```

Terminal run `npm -i axios` result:

[image]

Comment: What do you have in your CLI/terminal if you run `npm i axios`?

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` file?

Comment: I also get an error when I use npm i axios in the terminal, but it can be installed in the system terminal

Comment: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint-plugin-vue@8.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-vue@"^8.0.3" from the root project

Comment: Be sure to install nvm, this will provide you Node + npm properly: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: You also have some dependencies incompatibilities that you need to take care of as you can see in your last screenshot.

Comment: What's the meaning? Is this a problem with my dependencies?

Comment: Start by installing nvm properly. Then we'll see. Using `yarn` could also be a simpler fix overall (to solve those issues).

Comment: Get out of webstorm. On the command line, go to the root directory of your project where your package.json is, delete the entire node_modules folder, and run `npm install`. If it fails, make sure you're using the latest version of `npm`, and if you are, make sure all the version numbers in your package.json are up to date. For example `eslint-plugin-vue` is on [version 9.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-vue) now. Do NOT switch to yarn. 
 Delete this question and ask in a Reactiflux discord, there's too many comments here.

Comment: @AndyRay not sure what is the issue regarding yarn + comments here.

Comment: @kissu this person does not understand how npm, node, node_modules, nor dependencies work, nor do they understand how webstorm handles dependencies. Do NOT ask them to switch package managers when there are so many unknowns. Yarn has also fallen out of favor with node developers as it offers no benefits over npm.

Comment: @AndyRay the v7 is actually not fetching the peerDependecies by itself. So, if OP is using that one, there is something more to worry about. Hence why I recommended yarn here. Otherwise yeah, not everybody who posts here have all the mandatory basics, can't do much about that.